# please provide me some guidance, i get error here Caused By SQL error or missing database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i have a error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{snmn.sportsconnectapplication/snmn.sportsconnectapplication.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT name, locallatitude, locallongitude,
>   createdby, dateverified, verified FROM Locations
>
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>         (no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, locallatitude, locallongitude, createdby, dateverified, verified FROM
>   Locations)

My code

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + 
    DbContract.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        DbContract.NAME + "text, " +
        DbContract.LOCAL_LATITUDE + "text, " +
        DbContract.LOCAL_LONGITUDE + "text, " +
        DbContract.VERIFIED + "boolean, " +
        DbContract.DATE_VERIFIED + "date, " +
        DbContract.CREATED_BY +
        "text);";`

private static final String DROP_TABLE = "drop table if exists "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME;


public DbHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DbContract.DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void saveToLocalDatabase(String name, String locallatitude, String locallongitude, String createdby, Date dateverified, Boolean verified, SQLiteDatabase database){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DbContract.LOCAL_LATITUDE,locallatitude);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.LOCAL_LONGITUDE,locallongitude);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.CREATED_BY,createdby);
    contentValues.put (DbContract.DATE_VERIFIED, String.valueOf(dateverified));
    contentValues.put(DbContract.VERIFIED,verified);
    database.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
}
public Cursor readFromLocalDatabase (SQLiteDatabase database){
    String[] projection = {DbContract.NAME,DbContract.LOCAL_LATITUDE,DbContract.LOCAL_LONGITUDE,DbContract.CREATED_BY,DbContract.DATE_VERIFIED,DbContract.VERIFIED};
    return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need whitespace between column names and types. For example, change

```
DbContract.NAME + "text, " +
```

to

```
DbContract.NAME + " text, " +
```

After fixing these issues, you can uninstall and reinstall your app to retrigger `onCreate()`.

Comment: i have tried as you have said but its not working::   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
     (near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Locations(android.support.customtabs.customaction.ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, locallatitude TEXT, locallongitude TEXT, createdby TEXT, verified BOOLEAN, dateverified DATE );)

Comment: `android.support.customtabs.customaction.ID` does not belong there - you're messing something up.

Comment: it worked with some changes in the code but only when i uninstall the app and run again but not working when i dont uninstall it

Comment: @season that's because the databsehelper's  `onCreate` method is only called automatically once for the lifetime of the database (i.e. it's only called when the database doesn't exist and is then created).

Comment: The code you posted does not have that problem. Update your question with your followup issue.